# Entity Framework Migration (different time zones)

Tags: entity-framework

I've just started to investigate how to use the EF migration, but have already faced the problem. Let's imagine that two developers work with one solution, but they are in different time zones.

1. Dev1 creates the code-based migration with the name '201307151309449_7.cs' and commits it.
2. Dev2 is in another time zone (-3 hours), he gets the latest version from source control.
3. Dev2 executes the 'Update-Database' command. In this step Dev2 has the same DB-structure as the Dev1.
4. Dev2 makes some changes and creates migration called '201307151010092_8.cs'.

The migration with '_7' prefix was created earlier than '_8', but the visual studio stores the '201307151010092_8' migration like it was created first. As a result the code-based migration '201307151010092_8' won't contains any changes that the Dev2 made for himself (methods 'Up' and 'Down' are empty and I don't know why this is so).

Can someone explain to me how to use the EF Migration in such cases (different time zones) ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an EF bug and should be reported as an issue, if indeed it still exists in EF6.

One workaround I can think of could be applied with some co-ordination. That is to have Dev2 remove the '201307151309449_7' migration then generate their new migration and have it include both their own changes and Dev1's changes. Dev1 and Dev2 (and potentially others) would need to ensure that they took their databases back to the state before '201307151309449_7' via update-database -TargetMigration.

Another obvious workaround is to have Dev2 wait 3 hours!